# what's wrong in this awk print statement?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file test.txt below. Each line contains a value and the values are sequence of 6 values in the order of current1, voltage1, current2, voltage2, current3, voltage3. Below is the test.txt file.

```
11
12
13
14
15
16
21
22
23
24
25
26
31
32
33
34
35
36
41
42
43
44
45
46
```

Using awk, I want to print it in the format below(one set in one line).

```
11 12 13 14 15 16
21 22 23 24 25 26
31 32 33 34 35 36
41 42 43 44 45 46
```

So I wrote a simple awk script like below. I run a modular counter which runs from 1 to 6 and according to cnt value, I keep the input value in i1,v1,i2,v2,i3,v3 repectively. and when cnt is 6(when all the values in a set have been collected), I print the values.

```
BEGIN{cnt=1}
cnt == 1{i1 = $0}
cnt == 2{v1 = $0}
cnt == 3{i2 = $0}
cnt == 4{v2 = $0}
cnt == 5{i3 = $0}
cnt == 6{v3 = $0}
{if (cnt==6) {cnt = 1; print i1 v1 i2 v2 i3 v3} else cnt = cnt + 1}
```

The result is like below which is weird. It's been a while that I used awk so I can't figure out what is wrong with the script easily.

```
awk -f div.awk test.txt
16
26
36
46
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the output you want. You want V1 C1, V2, C2, V3, C3 then that pattern repeats on each line?

Comment: first i1 v1 i2 v2 i3 v4 pair is 11,12,13,14,15,16 and the second i1 v1 i2 v2 i3 v4 pair is 21,21,23,24,25,26, and so on.

Comment: Your code almost works for me, except it doesn't space the outputs, giving "111213141516" on the first line. I can't replicate what you see. I suspect your terminal is doing something odd, and its going to the start of the line before each output, and overwriting...

Comment: What does `echo 1 | awk '{a="AAA";b="BB"; print a b}'` show? It should show "AAABB", but if my hunch is right you'll see "BBA".

Comment: @Spacedman I tried the same code in cygwin and it works. As you said, my terminal in my linux machine is doing somethig weird. I'm happy to know that at least it works in cygwin. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulo operator. It should be:

```
awk 'NR%6{printf "%s ",$0}!(NR%6){print}' file
```

---

Btw, it looks like your file is using Windows line endings, which leads to the error you reported. Convert them to UNIX before using awk, for example:

```
sed 's/\r//' file | awk 'NR%6{printf "%s ",$0}!(NR%6){print}'
```

Comment: I see the same result. could you try it yourself? (because the sample file is simple..)   :)

Comment: I tried it myself. It appeared working, meaning it prints 6 columns per line.

Comment: BTW, 'condition{do this}!condition{do that}' is one of the tricks I wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: I found the code works in cygwin window. I don't know what's wrong with my linux terminal. and I'll bewaiting if someone could come up with a cure for my linux terminal...:)